Matrix computed via spectral decomposition is different than base matrix
def gauss_n(n):
    # Create tri-diagonal matrix

    A = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(1, n):
        curr_val = i/math.sqrt((4*(i**2))-1)  # Compute values
        A[i][i-1] = curr_val  # Place value
        A[i-1][i] = curr_val  # Place value symmetrically-opposite

    eig_values, eig_vectors = np.linalg.eig(A)  # Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors

    # Calculate: A = ZΛZ^T  - Spectral Decomposition (Z in this case is "eig_vectors")

    dia_eig = np.diag(eig_values)  # Create diagonal-matrix with eigenvalues (Λ)

    # Because our initial matrix was symmetrical, therefore it means that the set of eigenvectors are
    # all orthogonal to each other

    A2 = np.matmul(np.matmul(eig_vectors, dia_eig), np.linalg.inv(eig_vectors))  # The Z^T = Z^-1

That is the code that I've written so far (I included the math and the NumPy library). The way of computing the values on the tridiagonal is given by my homework instruction, but the thing is that at the end, my result of A2 is different of A, and I don't understand why
I tried changing the order which the A2 matrix is being computed, but doesn't change anything, or It doesn't get close to my expected result. Am I expecting A2 to be equal to A? If I'm wrong, could you explain why?

What you're doing seems to be correct, but you're getting rounding errors. You can verify with this: print(np.all(np.isclose(A, A2)))
Rounding errors are to be expected for numerical, as opposed to analytical, solutions. If you want analytical (exact) solutions, check out sympy, but that's usually not feasible for "real" stuff.
Also, as an addendum, a nicer way to write matrix multiplication is @. This is supported by numpy (and can be implemented in your own classes via __matmul__).
So you could do this:
eig_inv = np.linalg.inv(eig_vectors)
A2 = eig_vectors @ dia_eig @ eig_inv


I appreciate the help, I´ll try doing the recommendations. Thank you!

@DylanStreicher If that helped, I'd appreciate it if you'd accept this answer. Also, the recommendations are strictly optional, I just think it reads a bit nicer with @
